# Angular js - Binding to function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I have binding to function that looks something like that:

```
function func() {
    this.scopeVar = {
        bla: this.isolateScopeVar.bla,
        gla: this.isolateScopeVar.gla
    }
}
```

I have this html code:

```
<span>{{this.scopeVar.bla}}</span>
<span>{{this.scopeVar.gla}}</span>
```

My problem is that if the `this.isolateScopeVar.bla`or `this.isolateScopeVar.gla` has changed the `span` wouldn't updated without any trigger of `func`.

I can use this method which will work:

```
function func() {
    return {
        bla: this.isolateScopeVar.bla,
        gla: this.isolateScopeVar.gla
    }
}

<span>{{this.func().bla}}</span>
<span>{{this.func().gla}}</span>
```

But i think that this isn't the best way to do it.

There is any other way to do that correctly?

Comment: Why would you pass by a function to get these values? `this.isolateScopeVar.bla` is not working?

Comment: ^ or what syntax is used if you have `this.` ?

Answer (score 1):

let's start with, I hope you're using a recent version on angular, maybe with [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), that have isolated scope.

inside the template you can access the controller with `$ctrl`.

```
<span>{{$ctrl.bla}}</span>
```

where `bla` is defined inside the controller declaration:

```
angular.module('whatever').controller('theNameController', {
    bindings: {
        bla: '<' // if you want this to be settable from who's using the component
    },
    controller: () => {
        bla = 42; // or declare it here if you want it be completely isolated
    },
    require: { },
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here is example:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.component('appComponent', {
      template: [
        '<span>{{ $ctrl.getData().bla }}</span><br>',
        '<span>{{ $ctrl.getData().gla }}</span>',
      ].join(''),

      controller: function () {

        this.getData = function(){

          var isolateScopeVar = {}
          isolateScopeVar.bla = 'my item bla'
          isolateScopeVar.gla = 'my item gla'

          return {
              bla: isolateScopeVar.bla,
              gla: isolateScopeVar.gla
          }
        }
      }
});
```

Live demo is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/O2DSd7dH7akOgXD1pD0P?p=preview)